# Gerrit not showing commited files. Only lists "commit message" in the files

Tags: push, message, commit, gerrit

Whenever I push changes to gerrit that contain multiple files (I believe the threshold is over 10) gerrit doesn't display the modified files for review, it only displays the "commit message".

If the changes are approved, the code is properly merged, but in order to be reviewed the commit needs to be broken down so the files can be seen.

Is there a setting on Gerrit to limit the maximum number of files to display? 
   I noticed these warnings when pushing to gerrit, which I wonder if is enough for it lose track of the files:

**remote: (W) ad2789b: commit subject >65 characters; use shorter first paragraph
remote: (W) ad2789b: too many commit message lines longer than 70 characters; manually wrap lines**

This is what I see on gerrit:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: please make a shoot about the commit itself in the git repo browser. you can display it by clicking on next to the Commit hash

Answer (score 1):

This is not related with the number of changed files. This is happening because you're selecting "**Auto Merge**" at "Diff against" option. It seems that it's a merge commit done automatically so there're no differences between the "auto merge" and it. This is the default behaviour when you perform a merge without resolving conflicts.

Do some tests changing the "Diff against" option to "Parent 1" or "Parent 2" and see what happens.

Comment: aha. That might be it. I fixed it for now by using merge --squash, but I think you are onto something here. I'll create a reminder to myself to verify  this next time I merge. Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing necessarily wrong with merge commits. Probably you didn't have anything to fix, it was just a matter of understand how Gerrit is showing the merge information to you. The change is there... Gerrit is just saying that there isn't anything different from the merge done automatically.